# Why do I need to refresh page to make js work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a simple Rails 3.2 app and I'm experiencing an unexpected behavior.
Basically I have to refresh any page to make javascript to work.

This is my manifest

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require_tree .
```

And here the inclusion into my template

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Pretty standard stuff.

Anyone had experienced the same issue or has any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: are you bringing anything in via ajax? binding anything after the dom loads?

Comment: Are you saying that you load a page, nothing happens, and then reloading the same page makes the javascript work?

Comment: Exactly, for instance I have simple function that updates a div content as below.  

jQuery ->
  $(document).on "click", "[data-behavior~=toggle_visibility]", ->
    $.get("categories/", { visibility: $(this).data("visibility") }, null, "script")
    return false


It doesn't work when I first load the page, but after I press the reload button and the page is refreshed the link works.

Comment: Did you try : `$(document).ready ->` ?

Comment: Yes, for instance

$(document).ready ->
  $("#shipment_order_id").change ->
    component_code = $(this).find(":selected").data('component')
    $("#shipment_component_code").val(component_code)

and I need to refresh to make it work.

Comment: The issue seems connected to turbolinks. First time I use it so I'm not very familiar with it yet.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?  I'm not using "turbolinks".  I have the same problem... Its difficult to find information on.   I wondering whether it could be an HTML document header issue or something.